# Class directive not working when using ng-class to load the directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to load a 'class' directive using ng-class. but my directive is never loaded when i do that. The directive is a multipurpose directive, and I don't want to create an isolated scope on this. it will be loaded only when required, based on ng-class conditions hence not using attribute or element directive. has anyone tried doing this and succeeded?

this directive is called using `<div ng-class="someClass {{tooltip: enabled}}"></div>`
here `enabled` is a scope variable.

```
app.directive('tooltip', ['$timeout', '$location', '$rootScope', function (timer, $location, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var printContent = function () {
                /*  uses the content of .tooltip-content if it is a complex html tooltip, 
                    otherwise
                    you can use the title attribute for plaintext tooltips
                */
                var tooltipContent = $(element).find('.tooltip-content').html();
                if (!tooltipContent) {
                    tooltipContent = $(element).attr('title');
                }
                $(element).tooltip({
                    content: tooltipContent,
                    items: "img, a, span, button, div",
                    tooltipClass: "tooltip",
                    position: { my: "left+30 top", at: "right top", collision: "flipfit" },
                    show: { effect: "fadeIn", duration: "fast" },
                    hide: { effect: "fadeOut", duration: "fast" },
                    open: function (event, ui) { $rootScope.tooltipElement = event.target; }
                });
            };
            timer(printContent, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: may be you just forgot to set: `restrict: 'C'` ?

Comment: its set. please see my update to the post.

Comment: may be try this syntax: `class="someClass"  ng-class="{tooltip: enabled}"`

Comment: this did not work either. I have a little more information. The element that calls this directive, is a part of another template which is loaded as a part of another directive. Does this have anything to do with it? When i try to load the same directive as an attribute, it works fine.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue. It seems that you don't want to use the ng-class directive since that doesn't recompile the content after adding the class. You'll likely want to create your own dynamic-class directive that actually recompiles when the value is true:

```
app.directive('dynamicClass', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            dynamicClassWhen: '=',
            dynamicClass: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('dynamicClassWhen', function(val) {
                if (val) {
                    console.log(val);
                    elt.addClass(scope.dynamicClass);
                    $compile(elt)(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You may need to modify this for the ability to remove the class and depending on if the `$compile` is sufficient for you or if you need to further manipulate the html, but this seems to be the right track for you. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnMLj/) with this in action.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Re-`$compile`ing the element upon changes made by `ngClass` should be built into Angular core IMHO. Thanks hassassin for this idea. Incidentally, I tried it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733848/angularjs-attempt-to-dynamically-apply-directive-using-ngclass-causing-weird-fu and got some weird behaviour. Not sure if the problem was with your code, my implementation, or Angular, but I took another approach and didn't pursue it further.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I'm glad you found another approach, my answer seems to be working, in the contrived case. Your fiddle in the other question has the issue that it uses focused for all elements in things, also if you click an input once, it adds the class, if you focus again, it will add it AGAIN and compile (the number of directives increase). These things could be fixed, but an answer was accepted for that question. This one seems to fit here. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: We should probably be discussing this in the other thread, but... Yes, you're right I was going to add the `removeClass()` bit later, and didn't expect addClass to add the same class twice (it doesn't in jQuery). Your comment inspired me to add `else { elt.removeClass(scope.dynamicClass); }` and move the `$compile` outside the `if`, but that just crashes jsFiddle completely http://jsfiddle.net/ss6Y5/10/. If you wanna contribute a solution to the other thread, I'd at least upvote it. I like the pattern using your code much better, but I don't know if it's polite to retract an accepted answer!