# AngularJS: Attempt to dynamically apply directive using ngClass causing weird functional and performance issues

Tags: angularjs

### Requirement

1. I want a textarea that expands or contracts vertically as the user types, alla Facebook comment box.
2. When the textarea loses focus it contracts to one line (with ellipsis if content overflows) and re-expands to the size of the entered text upon re-focus (this functionality not found on Facebook)

Note: Clicking on the textarea should preserve caret position exactly where user clicked, which precludes any dynamic swapping of div for textarea as the control receives focus

### Attempted Solution

I'm already well into an AngularJS implementation, so...

1. Use [Monospaced's Angular Elastic plugin](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-elastic). Nice.
2. Two attempts...

   - Attempt A: `<textarea ng-focus="isFocussed=true" ng-blur="isFocussed=false" ng-class="'msd-elastic': isFocussed"></textarea>` Fails because ng-class triggers no re-`$compile` of the element after adding the class, so Angular Elastic is never invoked
   - Attempt B: create a custom directive that does the needed re-`$compile` upon class add. I used [this solution by hassassin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230011/class-directive-not-working-when-using-ng-class-to-load-the-directive).  Fails with the following problems

### Attempt B problems

Here's a [JSFiddle of Attempt B](http://jsfiddle.net/ss6Y5/5/)  Note that Angular v1.2.15 is used

I. Disappearing text

- go to the fiddle
- type into one textarea
- blur focus on that textarea (eg click in the other textarea)
- focus back on the text-containing textarea
- result: text disappears! (not expected or desired)

II. Increasingly excessive looping and eventual browser meltdown

- click into one textarea
- click into the other one
- repeat the above for as long as you can until the browser stops responding and you get CPU 100% or unresponsive script warnings.
- you'll notice that it starts out OK, but gets worse the more you click
- I confirmed this using: XP/Firefox v27, XP/Chrome v33, Win7/Chrome v33

### My investigations so far

It seems that `traverseScopesLoop` in AngularJS starting at line 12012 of v1.2.15, gets out of control, looping hundreds of times. I put a `console.log` just under the `do { // "traverse the scopes" loop` line and clocked thousands of loops just clicking.

Curiously, I don't get the same problems in Angular v1.0.4.  See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ss6Y5/3/) which is identical, except for Angular version

I logged this as an [AngularJS bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6902) and it was closed immediately, because I'd not shown it to be a bug in Angular per se.

### Questions

1. Is there another way to solve this to avoid the pattern in Attempt B?
2. Is there a better way to implement Attempt B?  There's no activity on that stackoverflow issue after hassassin offered the solution I used
3. Are the problems with Attempt B in my code, angular-elastic, hassassin's code, or my implementation of it all?  Appreciate tips on how to debug so I can "fish for myself" in future.  I've been using Chrome debug and Batarang for a half day already without much success.
4. Does it seem sensible to make a feature request to the AngularJS team for the pattern in Attempt A? Since you can add directives by class in Angular, and ngClass can add classes dynamically, it seems only natural to solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are severely overthinking this, and I can't think of any reason you would ever need to dynamically add / remove a directive, you could just as easily, inside the directive, check if it should do anything.  All you need to do is

1. Use the elastic plugin you are using
2. Use your own directive to reset height / add ellipsis when it doesn't have focus.

So something like this will work (not pretty, but just threw it together):
http://jsfiddle.net/ss6Y5/8/

```
angular.module("App", ['monospaced.elastic']).directive('dynamicClass', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: { ngModel: '=' },
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs, ngModel) {
      var tmpModel = false;
      var origHeight = elt.css('height');
      var height = elt.css('height');
      var heightChangeIndex = 0;
      scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
        if (elt.css('height') > origHeight && !heightChangeIndex) {
          heightChangeIndex = scope.ngModel.length;
          console.log(heightChangeIndex);
        }
        else if (elt.css('height') <= origHeight && elt.is(':focus')) {
          heightChangeIndex = 0;
        }
      });
      elt.on('blur focus', function() { 
        var tmp = elt.css('height');
        elt.css('height', height);
        height = tmp;
      });
      elt.on('blur', function() {
        if (height > origHeight) {
            tmpModel = angular.copy(scope.ngModel);
            ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.ngModel.substr(0, heightChangeIndex-4) + '...'); 
             ngModel.$render();
        }
      });
      elt.on('focus', function() {
       if (tmpModel.length) {
         scope.ngModel = tmpModel;
         ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.ngModel);
         ngModel.$render();
         tmpModel = '';
       }
        });

       }
      };
    })
```

Comment: The code you provided works, so job done! Thanks! :) I don't understand why you "can't think of any reason you would ever need to dynamically add / remove a directive". Wouldn't you rather one line of declarative code (ie Attempt A, if Angular supported it) than your 42 line directive?

Comment: In the end I had problems implementing this solution because it changes the model, causing all kinds of downstream hassles when saving to a database. Instead I chose to change the msd-elastic plugin to collapse the height on blur. Not ideal, but works because it only changes the textarea height, and not the data.